# jQuery not() selector problem

Tags: jquery

I have a depended radio groups, where by clicking on input#radio10, input#radio16 .form-block-cms should slide down. And no problems with that.

Problem is when I select input#radio16. form-block-cms slides down and back up straight away. I tried to use cond statements else if input#radio16 not selected, but it is still doing this.

How can I get around it please?

```
if ($('input#radio10, input#radio16').is(':checked')) {
    $('.rsform-block-cms').slideDown().addClass('additionalField')
}
else if ($('input#radio16').not(':checked')) {
    $('.rsform-block-cms').slideUp();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filters elements (but still returns a jQuery object, so it'll be ~= true), what you need instead is `!` and [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like this:

```
!$('input#radio16').is(':checked')
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
if ($('#radio10, #radio16').is(':checked')) {
   $('.rsform-block-cms').slideDown().addClass('additionalField')
} else if (!$('#radio16')[0].checked) {
   $('.rsform-block-cms').slideUp();
}
```

Comment: If there is no element with the ID "radio16" on the page, then `$("#radio16")[0].checked` will throw an error,ergo, break the program. It might be a good idea to guard against that. I used `$("#foo")[0] || {}` in my answer. What do you think?

Comment: @ime - This is a follow-up to another question...it'll be there :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use variables, so that you don't search for the same element twice...

```
var radio10 = $("#radio10")[0] || {};
var radio16 = $("#radio16")[0] || {};
var $rsfrom = $("#.rsform-block-cms");

if ( radio10.checked && radio16.checked ) {
    $rsform.slideDown().addClass("additionalField");
} else if ( !radio16.checked ) {
    $rsform.slideUp();
}
```

Not only does this have better performance, but it's also more readable :)